# When the below code is executed, firefox is showing error. I am using the latest version of java, eclipse, firefox, and WebDrive jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\vinil\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.jobserve.com/in/en/Job-Search/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddcl-selInd']/span/span")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

[[image: Error screenshot]]

Comment: And please, don't write the whole description in the title next time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on `driver.quit()` when you are closing the browser.

It is unfortunately known issue when quitting geckodriver firefox instance, see this links for details.

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7506 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027222